# AWS Cloudwatch multiregion logs insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm using AWS Cloudwatch Logs Insights to query loggroups. Now I implemented the application to the additional region. Is it possible to query loggroups from more than one region at once?
Thanks